# How to manage the risks of sleeping and cooking in a camper van?

Tags: safety, cooking, sleeping

There is a significant proportion of individuals who enjoy the Great Outdoors that also travel to the wilderness in vehicles converted for camping (RV, Vans, some boats etc).

For those living an outdoor/van/boat life experience what are the risks of sleeping and cooking in a confined, insulated vehicle, and, crucially, how can that be managed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The three risks that are relevant here are the risk of fire, suffocation and carbon monoxide poisoning

I'll take suffocation first. A gas leak can exclude oxygen to the point that you can no longer breathe, but there are standard mitigations:

- the gas canister is usually mounted external to the passenger cabin, in a compartment vented downwards, so that gas escaping a badly fitted connector will not enter the cabin.
- cookers typically have a safety cutoff that is heat operated, so if a flame blows out, the gas flow will stop.
- propane has a distinctive smell added, so it may wake you.
- while the main leak risk is from the connection to the canister, there is obviously a risk of leaks anywhere, so gas leak alarms are used

Carbon monoxide poisoning is unfortunately a bit more likely. Carbon monoxide is typically a byproduct of burning a flame without enough oxygen, so the usual mitigation is to have a window open. Simple but effective. Like the propane detectors, carbon monoxide detectors will loudly warn you of a leak

Fire (and explosion) is mitigated in the main by the cutoff and venting. When lighting a gas cooker, there is usually a requirement to hold the ignition until the flame has caught - and if the flame goes out, the cutoff will stop gas flow shortly afterwards. So the main fire risk when asleep is from leaving flames on - so checking all fire is out before going to bed is essential. No using the cooker as a heater when cold! Just wrap up warm.

Comment: A couple of additions not worth making my own answer for: if you need and you only have a stove, boil water for a hot water bottle, even improvised - but of course ventilate while burning; if possible have a high vent to let CO (and steam) out and a low vent for fresh air to come in. Shut them as soon as you've turned the gas off; watch out for curtains vs flames - thick curtains keep the heat in but can hang awkwardly.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that if you heat or cook with propane (or LPG), then you have the same sorts of problems in a house as in an RV.  For instance, the local authorities (California/Nevada Sierras) are warning people to clear the current 10-20 ft (3-6 m) accumulation of snow off their propane tanks because it can cause leaks, and consequent fires/explosions.

Comment: I believe the OP is in the UK where butane is more common for the smaller cylinders. And while it has a smell it's not the mercaptan smell of domestic gas.

Comment: If hes in the UK (and most other countries), there are standards and regulations that must be met to install a gas appliance. Meeting these regulations is a pretty good assurance you installation is safe.  The addition of CO, LPG and Smoke alarms is cheap insurance.

Comment: One not on smelling Propane - You probably won't smell it once asleep- you will wake up and still not be able to smell it. More than one person has been lucky enough to wake up with a head ache, but unlucky enough to think a cup of tea will help.

Comment: I should stress **may**

Comment: If a [catalytic heater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_heater) is used, the oxygen in the vehicle can be consumed by the chemical reaction even in the absence of a gas leak.

Comment: @mattnz; they regulations you are referring to exist for domestic gas appliances (boilers, cookers etc).  They are not enforced for things like barbecues and camper stoves which are not subjected to review or inspection.

Comment: Yes, regulations are not enforced for portable cookers, it does not change the fact that meeting them (or at least the intent of the standards) ensures a degree of safety.

Comment: Additionally only ever use low pressure appliances inside and RV/Car/Van. Have the bottle and regulator installed in a vented compartment sealed from the interior. If a high pressure setup develops a leak, large amounts of gas are released very quickly. Low pressure regulators restrict the gas at a maximum flow rate and some even cut off the supply if the flow rate is exceeded.